# iFrame option in media plugin for TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, iframe, tinymce, media

When you look at the [demo of tinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/tryit/full.php), and click on the *media* button, you can find the options HTML5 Video and iFrame.
Now, when I download the newest version of TinyMCE I see that these options are missing!
Because I would like to have the iFrame option in my own TinyMCE editor, I'm asking you:

How can I get this option too?

P.S.: The version I'm using is 3.4.2

Answer (score 2):

You need to add/enable the media plugin to get this to work

See [http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Plugin:media](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Plugin%3amedia)

Comment: Hi, I already have enabled this plugin, but I'm mising the options of the media type: HTML5Video and iFrame.

Comment: @gigha To insert an iFrame you can modify the plugin's default behavior as shown in the aforementioned documentation. Just scroll down.